# Close menu on click link

Tags: javascript

I want to close the menu when I click on a link. Do you have an idea why my code does not work? [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tixukizixa/edit?html,js,console,output)

```js
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    console.log("ok");
    menu.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<ul  class="nav__right" id="menu">
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#home">home</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#about">À propos</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#production">Réalisations</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want to hide `li` element if it's clicked?

Comment: Try `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @Fr33d0m Problem is the condition is not being met.

Comment: I have tried using e.target.nodeName=='A' in the if condition and it seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target.nodeName` returns `A` whereas you are comparing it with `LI`.

```js
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName);
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
    console.log("ok");
    this.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<ul  class="nav__right" id="menu">
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#home">home</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#about">À propos</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#production">Réalisations</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two silly mistakes. First, `menu` is an undefined variable. You obviously meant `document.getElementById('menu')`. Last, the `nodeName`method will return "A", not "LI". Here is the corrected code:

```js
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
    console.log("ok");
    this.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<ul  class="nav__right" id="menu">
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#home">home</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#about">À propos</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#production">Réalisations</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No need to do `document.getElementById("menu")` twice. `this.style.display = 'none'` will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html

```
 <li>
      <h3><a href="#home">home</a></h3>
 </li>
```

Your condition is wrong actuallly. You just checking for `LI`. Where as the click even may be link (`A`) or the whole line (`H3`) on anything.

```
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",function(e) {

if((e.target) && (e.target.nodeName == "LI" || e.target.nodeName == "H3" ||e.target.nodeName == "A")){
    console.log("ok");
    this.style.display = "none";
}
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/xotoratune/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: No need to do `document.getElementById("menu")` twice. `this.style.display = 'none'` will do.

Comment: @Fahmi True. Just copy pasted OP code. Thanks. Corrected,

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul  class="nav__right" id="menu">
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#home">home</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#about">À propos</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#production">Réalisations</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h3>
  </li>
</ul>

$(function () {
    var sf_menu_sub = $('.nav__right');
    $('.nav__right').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        sf_menu_sub.hide();
    });
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        sf_menu_sub.hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.nodeName` of the clicked element is `A` which a child of `H3` which the child of `LI` so you can match it like this:

`e.target.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == "LI"`

you can also add extra checks if you want to

- `e.target.parentNode.nodeName == "H3"`
- `e.target.nodeName == "A"`